# Drawing 3D Circle

Tags: c#, sharpdx

I most recently started to use sharpdx and simply liked using it until I ran into the issue of drawing a 3D non-filled circle (X,Y,Z). For now all I'm wanting to do is draw a circle (XYZ) on a SharpDX form (testing purposes for now). I tried to start but I'm not experienced enough with SharpDX to do it yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 3D Circle = Sphere

Comment: Oh my thanks for clearing that up. Solved